# Replace a specific part of a string

Tags: mysql, update, replace

I have many strings in the database like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8&index=8&list=PLPNcLSfYNC3Dw535smncyHRCBRmdf1Bti"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

#### Original

`www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8&index=8&list=PLPNcLSfYNC3Dw535smncyHRCBRmdf1Bti`

#### Desired

`www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8`

So final string can be converted to:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-qTiYA1WiY8"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can do this using PHP, but I want to do it with a MySQL query. I tried to use:

```
UPDATE MyTable    
    SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'SearchForThis', 'ReplaceWithThis')
```

It needs to be a general solution that can replace string from `&` and before `"` if exist in the string. I am not able to get the proper result.

Comment: MariaDB has REGEXP_REPLACE; MySQL does not.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are all the same, and the column is called `c1` in a table called `t1` then `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` might get you there.  Don't update your table until you've verified it with `SELECT`.

Whitespace added for clarity.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(c1,'&',1),
  '"',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(c1,'"',-3)
) FROM t1;
```

SELECT the substring left of the first '&' counting from the left, a literal " and then the substring right of the third " counting from the right.

The only caveat is that the link format you've shown seems wrong.  The first "&" seems like it should have been "?" instead, and you should be clipping it at the "?" which marks the start of the query string in a URL.  Perhaps youtube was doing something nonstandard with URLs to work around plugin or browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be:

Run query with two conditions:

1. Get the substring out of the string that you want to replace with blank characters. Example:

   ```
   SELECT RIGHT(StringColumn,LOCATE('&',StringColumn))
   ```

   This will return the characters to the right of the '&' .
2. Merge this with the `REPLACE` function. Example:

   ```
   UPDATE MyTable 
   SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, (
       SELECT RIGHT(StringColumn,LOCATE('&',StringColumn))) , '')
   ```